# Load and Save nodes with script?

Tags: 7

I have about 30,000 nodes I need to load and resave so things like autotags and url aliases get generated.  Is there a quick script I can write to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to resaving for smaller count of nodes, and run next script few times. Of course using [batch](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/batch/7) will better UI, add itself:

```
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$from_nid = variable_get('tmp_from_nid', 0);

$sql = "SELECT n.nid
        FROM {node} n
        WHERE n.nid > :nid
        ORDER BY n.nid";
$result = db_query_range($sql, $from, 1000, $from_nid);

foreach($result as $row) { 
  set_time_limit(30);

  $node = node_load($row->nid);
  node_save($node);
  $from_nid = $row->nid;
}

variable_set('tmp_from_nid', $from_nid);
drupal_set_message(t('Last processed nid - !nid', array('!nid' => $from_nid)));
?>
```

Also [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) for mass resaving nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
#!/user/bin/env drush
<?php 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$nodes = node_load_multiple(NULL, array('type' => "my_type"));
foreach ($nodes as $nid => $node) {
  // Do some stuff here.
  node_save($node);
  drupal_is_cli() && drush_print("Re-saved node $node->nid");
}
```

It can work also as a drush script (`drush scr`).