# Programmatically submit form / save all nodes

Tags: forms, nodes

After migrating all the content from a drupal 6 installation to a drupal 7 one, I ended up with empty fields in my nodes, that are displayed when viewing the node.

However if I edit the node without changing anything and save it, the empty fields are gone (at that point the save function populates the database with the proper null values).

Obviously I can't do that by hand and the solution proposed here: [Load and Save nodes with script?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12366/load-and-save-nodes-with-script) doesn't remove the empty fields, even if I actually edit one of the fields. I would like to do this with a php script as I am not familiar at all with Python and the selenium script proposed here: [How to programmatically iterate over nodes, load into form, and save the form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19716/how-to-programmatically-iterate-over-nodes-load-into-form-and-save-the-form).

Now as far as Drupal's `form_submit` method, how does it actually populate the `$form`, `$form_state` variables since I won't be changing anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think trying to fake form submissions is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

I don't think trying to fake form submissions is a good idea - there is a lot that goes on behind the scenes, and it is easy to get something wrong.

I would suggest instead you implement a script similar to the one you pointed out in [Load and Save nodes with script?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12366/load-and-save-nodes-with-script) in which you actually set the missing values to the empty data you require. In that script, after the `node_load` (and before the `node_save`) you could do something like:

```
$empty_value = array(
  'value' => ''
);
$node->field_my_custom_field[$node->language] = array(
  0 => $empty_value
);
```

You would need to do this for each field that needs fixing. The value you need for `$empty_value` will depend on the field type. You could work it out dynamically by calling [field_info_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) ;  however as your script is a one-off, it's simpler to just set the right value for each field. To know what the right empty value should be, just create a node with the right empty value and then inspect it (eg. using `var_dump`, `dpm`, etc.)